# Batch Code Win7 Outputing to file doesnt work but appending it does?

Tags: batch-file, file-io

So im working on a batch file that can Extract certain lines of text from a massive number of txt files. I had it working fine inside 1 folder but I needed it to be recursive so I changed it up a bit, and It no longer Outputs anything to a text file

```
for /r %%Z in (*.as) do (
SET /a count=0
set /a non_eng=0
echo z = %%Z
pause
    for /F "eol=; tokens=1,2 usebackq delims=(" %%A in ("%%Z") do (
        set /a count+=1
        if /i %%A==texte echo !count!=%%A(%%B
    ) > "%%Z.txt"
    Echo Writting To File %%Z.txt
    pause
if exist "%%Z" echo LC_!count! >> "%%Z.txt")
```

This Line No longer works

> ) > "%%Z.txt"

But if I change it to >> it works fine... Problem Is it doubles up the copied text each time...

[Working version (just doesn't delve into directories)](http://pastebin.com/7MdsUPW6)

PS: I Worked around this issue but Im still unsure as to what caused the problem in the first place at the very least I believe I should have been geting at least one line of correct output to the file.

Comment: Without sample data, it's kind of hard to tell what's wrong, but if I had to made an educated guess, I'd recommend changing `echo !count!=%%A(%%B` to `echo !count!=%%A^(%%B`. You may also need to change `delims=(` to `delims=^(`.

Comment: Heres an Example of the line its grabbing 

textE("莉 央\nすごい、すごい！！おしゃれなところだねー！");

I'm just confused why ">" Doesnt work but ">>" does and Why ">" Worked Before i made it able to go through all sub folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your working code has the redirection placed at the `for` loop that iterate the files, not the `for /f` that reads them. In this way there is one `open/write/close` on the log file for each file being processed, with all the data echoed inside redirected to the output file.

But in the non working version, you have the redirection at the `for /f` that reads the files. Now you have a `open/write/close` operation for each of the lines of the file being processed. And, as the redirection is `>`, only the last execution of the `for /f` is saved in the file.

The simplest way to avoid it is to enclose the inner `for` loop in parenthesis and redirect this block

```
( 
    for /f .... %%A in (...) do (
        ....
    )
) >  "%%Z.txt"
```